# Injecting and modifying C# executable

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering

I would like to ask if it is possible to somehow inject C# code to an existing *.exe file that is also written in C# without decompiling it.

In other words, I'm trying to make an "extension" to an already existing C# program, but I would like to modify it without any manipulation with the "base" code (the .*exe file).

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or is the decompilation process required to modify base code's methods, classes and/or add extensions to it, etc. ?

Comment: You *can* edit the IL code directly without decompliling it into C#, editing the C#, and then recompiling it, but odds are that's going to be *harder* for you, not easier.

Comment: Have you looked at [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: @Servy editing the IL is still decompiling the executable.

Comment: I agree with Servy, while its possible to inject C# code into a C# process or executable, its an entirely complex to develop an "extension" for the process and inject that. Modifying return values of functions, is simple, the other requires a lot more work.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the various reflection namespaces as you may be able to do something with that. Otherwise you would have to decompile to CIL and go from there

Comment: @Jetti Decompiling the IL would mean translating the IL back into C# code.  You don't *need* to do that to edit the code's IL, even though that's the most practical means.  Editing the IL code directly is just editing the IL code.  Compiling is the process of translating code from one language to another; editing IL isn't changing the language of that code.

Comment: @Jetti Not necessarily, see https://github.com/punitganshani/codeinject

Comment: @Ron Beyer, CodeInject uses reflection which is what I suggested to use.

Comment: @Jetti It was just an example, but it does not require decompilation (what your original comment said, not the edited one).

Comment: @Servy - CIL is the assembly of a .net executable. In order to view that assembly you need to decompile it. You wouldn't say that viewing the assembly of a native executable is not decompiling. It is the same thing here. You can transpile the CIL to C# and work on it or you can modify the CIL directly.

Comment: @RonBeyer I never edited a comment. My point is that modifying any CIL directly requires decompilation. You can use reflection to avoid having to decompile an exe and be able to access everything in C#

Comment: Okay, let's say, I am able to decompile the whole *.exe file and then read methods' names, return values, parameters etc. Is there an easy way to actually modify a whole method (like, add a call to another method to its body) without the decompilation process (if I already know the target method's name)?

Comment: @RonBeyer The link you have provided only have the implementation of Logger via IL which is really hard to understand if you're not familiar with IL code before. I recently came across a library which provides wrapper over IL codes and is Fluent in usage. see https://github.com/FluentIL/FluentIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it by using frameworks like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) or [Microsoft CCI project](https://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/). These frameworks allows you to read & modify/inject IL. But it's not easy to learn those frameworks and IL codes usage.

Thought there's a library available [FluentIL](https://github.com/ElemarJR/FluentIL) which is build on top of [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) provides C# wrapper for IL Code. It doesn't Decompile the assembly rather it loads it, inject the assembly can writes/generates a new one with injected code.

Here's a sample that I used to inject "Null Checking code" in methods where arguments are marked with `[NotNull]` in project assembly post compilation.

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(SourceAssemblyPath);
var module = assembly.MainModule;

var q = from type in module.Types
        from method in type.Methods
        from parameter in method.Parameters
        where parameter.HasCustomAttributes
        from attribute in parameter.CustomAttributes
        where attribute.AttributeType.FullName == NotNullAttribute.FullName
        select new { Method = method, Parameter = parameter };

foreach (var item in q)
{
    item.Method.InsertBefore()
        .Ldarg(item.Parameter.Name)
        .IfNull()
            .Throw<ArgumentNullException>()
        .EndIf();
}

SourceAssemblyPath = SourceAssemblyPath.Replace("\\debug\\", "\\release\\");
assembly.Write(SourceAssemblyPath, new WriterParameters { WriteSymbols = false });
```